# Unable to receive response from PHP to Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, response

This is my absolute first try on the subject:
I'm sending data throw email using javascript and PHP.
I have read previous responses on the subject, but I can't make it work.
My js code:

```
const messagesend = document.getElementById('message_form');
 messagesend.addEventListener('submit', (eee) => {
     eee.preventDefault();
     var messageData = new Object();
     messageData.name = document.getElementById('conname').value;
     messageData.email = document.getElementById('conemail').value;
     messageData.message = document.getElementById('conmessage').value;
     messageData.verification = 'drovarcrete_message';
     var messageString = JSON.stringify(messageData);
 
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: 'messageSender.php',
         data: messageString,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
              alert("Message send.");
              $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
              $('#email_success_info').modal('show');
            
         }
     });

 });

 $("#modal2_close").click(function() {
     $('#email_success_info').modal('hide');
 });
```

My PHP works fine, with last line being:
echo 'Message send';
I have also tried: echo json_encode(array('success' => true));

However, the alert message doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and see what is going on with your request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: 'messageSender.php',
    data: messageString,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Message send.");
        $('#contactModal').modal('hide');
        $('#email_success_info').modal('show');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error.responseText);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Javascript still doesn't respond as I want. I view a ton of information in chrome inspect console (info about the email sent and the string response echoed from PHP file, but the commands in my ajax success: {} are not executed.

Comment: Can you share your PHP code? The success commands are not executed because there is an error somewhere

Comment: Τhank you for your answers. I switched to  $mail->SMTPDebug = false; in my php file and It works fine.